# How to connect from local window to aws linux mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, networking, pymysql

I have a question about connecting mysql from local windows to aws linux.

I am using 3 machines.

```
first : Mac
second : Windows (Mac is being used remotely)
third : AWS linux
```

I want to insert data into mysql on aws linux from linux and windows.
The code uses Python and the code below is the code that tested the insert.

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='..ip address..',
                       user='grafana',
                       password='testgraf12',
                       db='grafana',
                       charset='utf8')
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = """
        INSERT INTO test_table (date_id, time_id)
        VALUES (%s, %s)
      """

cursor.execute(sql, ('tt', 'te@example.com'))
cursor.execute(sql, ('eesstt', 'st@example.com'))
conn.commit()
```

I created a mysql inbound rule in aws.
In Linux, data is normally inserted into aws mysql.

But on Windows, which I am using remotely, if I run the same code
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '..ip address..' (timed out)") error It happens.

The grafana page using Linux mysql can be accessed from both Mac and Window.

May i know why this is like this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a tunnel for this to work

The below example is for postgresql, however you can use the following steps for mysql too.

First - I logged onto EC2, installed postgresql and did a connectivity check

```
[ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-44 ~]$ sudo su -
[root@ip-192-168-1-44 ~]# yum install postgresql

[root@ip-192-168-1-44 ~]# psql --host=database-1.coiobmxe1gzr.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=postgres --password
Password for user postgres: 
psql (9.2.24, server 13.7)
WARNING: psql version 9.2, server version 13.0.
         Some psql features might not work.
SSL connection (cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.
```

2. Here is my tunnel is running on one terminal - this is like a daemon

```
ssh -N -L 3336:127.0.0.1:5432 ec2-user@54.88.192.213
```

3. on another terminal

```
psql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 --username=postgres --password
Password: 
psql (14.5)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SELECT *
postgres-# FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
postgres-# WHERE schemaname != 'pg_catalog' AND 
postgres-#     schemaname != 'information_schema';
 schemaname | tablename | tableowner | tablespace | hasindexes | hasrules | hastriggers | rowsecurity 
------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sri
But, still not operate.. same reason.